# Make an SVG fill the entire page exactly

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am making a simple single-page application in plain Javascript and want to use a full-page SVG as the graphics foundation.

I would have thought that putting

```
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
```

in the page body would do the trick. It almost works, but not quite:

- the page has a vertical scrollbar (which I wouldn't expect because `100%` should not mean "greater than 100%" and therefore there should be nothing to scroll to).
- the SVG top-left corner is about 20 pixels into the page (in both dimensions)
- the right side of the SVG is truncated -- about 10 pixel columns are blank between the SVG and the scrollbar (that I don't even want nor expect).

To show these problems clearly, I added Javascript code to draw a big bounding rectangle with an X in it after retrieving the SVG client coordinates.

```html
<html><body>

<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>

<script>

let svg = document.getElementById("svg");

function line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
{
    let e = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'line');
    e.setAttribute('x1', x1);
    e.setAttribute('y1', y1);
    e.setAttribute('x2', x2);
    e.setAttribute('y2', y2);
    e.setAttribute('style', 'stroke:#000');
    svg.appendChild(e);
}

function frame_rect(r)
{
    let e = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'rect');
    e.setAttribute('x', r.x);
    e.setAttribute('y', r.y);
    e.setAttribute('width', r.width);
    e.setAttribute('height', r.height);
    e.setAttribute('style', 'stroke:#000;fill:none');
    svg.appendChild(e);
}

onresize = function()
{
    svg.innerHTML = ''; // remove all elements from the SVG
    let r = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
    line(r.x,r.y,r.x+r.width,r.y+r.height);
    line(r.x,r.y+r.height,r.x+r.width,r.y);
    frame_rect(r);
}
onresize()

</script></body></html>
```

Any thoughts on what is crufting up the SVG bounds? Perhaps some kind of border defaults or CSS defaults or some wonderful thing like that?

Comment: Have you tried setting the height and width with css instead of attributes? And zeroing out all css defaults (lots of examples of that online)

Comment: @Anthony. Hmm... tried `<style>#svg {width:100%; height:100%}</style>` which seems to have the same effect as attributes on the SVG itself... now I'll try finding those defaults you speak of.

Comment: Try adding `html, body, * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: @Anthony YES!  !

Comment: With `<style>html, body, * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }</style>
<svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>` it is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Nice! Added as answer.

Comment: @Anthony  good answer.  You may also use max-width & max-height min-width &min-height. As it prevents varying in dimensions from device to other .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to zero out the default margin and padding in CSS like:

```
html, body, * { 
     margin: 0; 
     padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for finding this; it's great! Note: `body { margin: 0;}` also works (which we could also write simply as `<body style="margin:0">`). Is there any advantage to the other commands that you suggested in your answer? (i.e., the `padding:0` and the `html` and `*`)

Comment: A few things: 1. It's generally better to handle CSS at a page level rather than inline (this allows more portability and separation of concerns) 2. Every browser is free to apply whatever default styles they like, and the ones that throw off layout for most designers and developers are usually margins and padding. 3. I hesitate to zero out everything using the wildcard selector, but it's a common approach to this problem, so I was mostly parroting that since you'll likely encounter it if you dig further into the topic.

Comment: Good point about expanding to more browsers. On Edge I need to add `overflow:hidden` as well; I think this hides padding that is specific to Edge. Actually it would be better to figure out *why* Edge is adding padding at the bottom, as `html, body, * {margin:0; padding:0;}` is not enough.

Comment: Slight problem here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56333749/svg-element-not-receiving-onclick-in-chrome